# Is there any way to navigate/list available roles when restricting an API visibility by roles

Tags: wso2-api-manager

At the moment we're asking users to enter role names when restricting APIs by roles. Users (API publishers) have to know the roles beforehand. If it's LDAP then they have to use an LDAP browser or ask an admin to provide a list of roles.
After typing a role we're doing a validation check to make sure role is valid. If we can extend this to list out / browse all available roles and let the user to select a subset, that'll provide a better user experience
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, WSO2 APIM publisher rest API does not have such resource to get the list of roles. It only has a role validation endpoint.